# update value of a panelPopup

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, xhtml, icefaces

I have a problem with ICEFaces to update the value of my **ice:panelPopup**. I have a value **wbw** in my **main.xhtml** page:

```
<ice:inputText value="#{main.wbw}" size="5">
    <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="2" maxFractionDigits="2" />
</ice:inputText>
```

[image]

I have included a second xhtml page in my main xhtml page:

```
<ui:include src="/resources/includs/second.xhtml" />
```

In my **second.xhtml** i have the same value as it is in the **main.xhtml**:

```
<ice:inputText value="#{main.wbw}"/>
```

[image]

The problem is, when i change the value in my **second.xhtml** the value automaticly changes in the **main.xhtml**, BUT when i close the popup and i change the value in my **main.xhtml** page, he doesnt update and he doesnt change the value in my **second.xhtml** page, so that the popup doesnt update and keeps the old value inside. Somebody knows how to update the value?

Comment: Did you use the `render` attribute?

Comment: no i dont use the render attribute, because it is only for rendering the component or not. So if i put render="false" the whole input component wont be rendered. So it is not that what i need. I know that in Primefaces there is an "update" attribute which do exactly that what i need but ICEFaces doesnt have this.

Comment: IceFaces **does** have an 'update'... where did you read they did not?

Comment: I have not found one. Can you show me?

Comment: `render` sets components' ids to re-render, it is only exists on AJAX based components. What you mixed it with is `rendered`... (In `JSF` 1.x `render` was called `reRender`...)

Comment: Ok i did not know that. And do i need to put the ID of the main.xhtml's input component into the render attribute of the second.xhtml's input component?

Comment: No, you need an AJAX component, like `ice:ajax`, that is attached to the main.xhtml's input component, and re-renders the other one. You need to ad an `id` attribute to the other one, to be able to list its `id` into the `ice:ajax`'s `render` attribute...

Comment: Can you post an example please?

Comment: I tried it and it doesnt work for me:

<ace:ajax execute="@this" render=":form:secondWBW"/> or
<ace:ajax execute="@this" render=":secondWBW"/> or
<ace:ajax execute="@this" render="secondWBW"/>

Answer (score 0):

I found out why it is not updating. When the popup menu is closed the status of the menu is like hidden so that the values in that menu does not exist in the lifecycle. At the moment when you open the popup they get created. So when it is closed the inputText is undefined. When you open the popup menu you need to update the value via javascript.

```
var wbw = document.getElementById(inputText_id of main.xhtml).value;
if (document.getElementById(inputText_id of second.xhtml) != null)
    document.getElementById(inputText_id of second.xhtml).value = wbw;
```

This solution worked for me. I jsut updatet the value via javascript after i opened the popup menu.